# Finding letters in string, not followed by a number... possibly using RE?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to extract letters from a string, which do not follow, or are not followed directly by a number.

Here's an example string:

```
string = "ts0060_LOD-70234_lr2_billboards_rgba_over_s3d_lf_v5_2Kdciufa_lnh"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
re.findall(r"[a-z]+", string.lower())
```

which gives this result:

```
['ts', 'lod', 'lr', 'billboards', 'rgba', 'over', 's', 'd', 'lf', 'v', 'kdciufa', 'lnh']
```

... but the result I am looking for is something more like this:

```
['lod', 'billboards', 'rgba', 'over', 'lf', 'lnh']
```

Is there a way of achieving this using regular expressions?

Many thanks,

Comment: reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html (negative lookahead and negative lookbehind are the relevant tools.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use negative look-arounds:

```
re.findall(r"(?<![\da-z])[a-z]+(?![\da-z])", string.lower())
```

This matches lower-case letters that are *not* immediately preceded or followed by more letters or digits.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "ts0060_LOD-70234_lr2_billboards_rgba_over_s3d_lf_v5_2Kdciufa_lnh"
>>> re.findall(r"(?<![\da-z])[a-z]+(?![\da-z])", string.lower())
['lod', 'billboards', 'rgba', 'over', 'lf', 'lnh']
```

Comment: If you know that the delimiters are going to be `_` and `-`, couldn't you use that knowledge to avoid using lookaround altogether?

Comment: Something like: `[_-]([a-z]+)[_-]` although this doesn't handle the initial non-underscore/dash or the end case.  But I like your answer better regardless.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: because then those would be included in the output or you'd have to add a group. And the last required match doesn't end with a `_` or `-`. You could work around that but then you'd end up with something uglier than look-arounds anyway.

Comment: genius... thank you. I am still quite new to regular expressions, this is super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using `findall` is to split the string into individual words, and then filter out any words containing non-alphabetical characters.

```
import re

string = "ts0060_LOD-70234_lr2_billboards_rgba_over_s3d_lf_v5_2Kdciufa_lnh"

#split on non-alphanumeric characters
words = re.split("[^a-z0-9]", string.lower())
print "words:", words

filtered_words = filter(str.isalpha, words)
print "filtered words:", filtered_words
```

Result:

```
words: ['ts0060', 'lod', '70234', 'lr2', 'billboards', 'rgba', 'over', 's3d', 'lf', 'v5', '2kdciufa', 'lnh']
filtered words: ['lod', 'billboards', 'rgba', 'over', 'lf', 'lnh']
```

Comment: This is a very good solution, and one that is more readable. +1