# How can I add in a list some items from a text file?

Tags: python, list

I'm setting up a script and I need to get some values from a text file.

The architecture of the text file is:

```py
ABC;
XYZ
 1 2
 3 4;
DEF;
XYZ
 7 8
 9 10
 11 12;
GHI;
```

The objective is to obtain this output:

```py
values_list = ['XYZ 1 2 3 4', 'XYZ 7 8 9 10 11 12']
```

in order to write it on a new text file that I'll create.

I've tried this:

```py
my_file = open(file, 'r')
content = my_file.read()
line = my_file.readline()
if line.startwith('XYZ'):
   values_list.append(line)
```

but this obviously doesn't work but I don't find a way to translate the fact to add the list all the lines after `XYZ`.

Comment: post a valid output as how it should really look

Comment: `[XYZ 1 2 3 4, XYZ 7 8 9 10 11 12]` isn't a proper list, how do you want the values to be separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
print(list(map(str.split, content.split(';')[1::2][:-1])))
```

Output:

```
[['XYZ', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['XYZ', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']]
```

If you want integers:

```
print([i[:1] + list(map(int, i[1:])) for i in list(map(str.split, content.split(';')[1::2][:-1]))])
```

Output:

```
[['XYZ', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['XYZ', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: The fact is that I've added `ABC` as an example but there is not only `ABC` and 'XYZ` in my file. I'll updated my question. Moreover, your output is a list of list, but does a way exist to only get a list with the string?

Comment: @Bandoleras I edited my answer, please check it now, and if it works please accept it and up-vote it

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex

**Ex:**

```
import re
with open(filename) as infile:
    data = infile.read()

result = [" ".join(i.splitlines()).strip(";") for i in re.findall(r"([A-Z]+(?![;A-Z]).*?)[A-Z]+;", data)]   #Regex Help --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709242/532312
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['XYZ  1 2  3 4', 'XYZ  7 8  9 10  11 12']
```

Comment: P.S. it's not always `ABC`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the lines, and concatenate lines that follows the `XYZ` lines and do some string manipulation in the process:

```
In [48]: with open('file.txt') as f: 
    ...:     out = [] 
    ...:     text = '' 
    ...:     for line in f: 
    ...:         if line.startswith('XYZ'): 
    ...:             text = 'XYZ' 
    ...:         elif text.startswith('XYZ') and line.startswith(' '): 
    ...:             text += line.rstrip(';\n') 
    ...:         else: 
    ...:             if text: 
    ...:                 out.append(text) 
    ...:             text = '' 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [49]: out                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[49]: ['XYZ 1 2 3 4', 'XYZ 7 8 9 10 11 12']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `re`:

```
data = '''ABC;
XYZ
 1 2
 3 4;
DEF;
XYZ
 7 8
 9 10
 11 12;
GHI;'''

import re

out = [re.sub(r'\n|;', '', g, flags=re.M) for g in re.split(r'^\w+;', data, flags=re.M) if g.strip()]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['XYZ 1 2 3 4', 'XYZ 7 8 9 10 11 12']
```

Answer (score 1):

Short regex approach:

```
import re

with open(file.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()
    repl_pat = re.compile(r'\s+')
    values = [repl_pat.sub(' ', s.group()) 
              for s in re.finditer(r'\bXYZ\s+[^;]+', content, re.M)]
    print(values)
```

The output:

```
['XYZ 1 2 3 4', 'XYZ 7 8 9 10 11 12']
```